# Codeigniter or_where is not working together with or_like

Tags: codeigniter

the $this->db->or_where($where); it not working.. it doesn't return and value.. but when I remove the or_like() statements it works fine.. can't or_where work together with or_like? help please..

```
    public function search(){

    $capacity1 = $this->input->post('capacity1');
    $capacity2 = $this->input->post('capacity2');
    $capacity3 = $this->input->post('capacity3');
    $capacity4 = $this->input->post('capacity4');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $establishment_type = $this->input->post('type');
    $price = $this->input->post('price');

    $cprice = intval($price);


    if($price == "1499"){
      echo "1499";
    $where = "price < 1500";

    $this->db->or_where($where);
  }


    $this->db->or_like('capacity', $capacity1);
    $this->db->or_like('capacity', $capacity2);
    $this->db->or_like('capacity', $capacity3);
    $this->db->or_like('capacity', $capacity4);
    $this->db->or_like('type', $establishment_type);
    $this->db->or_like('gender', $gender);


    $query = $this->db->get('establishment');




    return $query->result_array();


}
```

Comment: the or_where function requires 2 parameters, like this; $this->db->or_where('price <', 1500);

Comment: or_where still doesn't work with or_like, but then I remove the or_like statements.. it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `where()` instead of `or_where()`. Then your code will produce something like:

"`WHERE price < 1500 or capacity LIKE '%yourcapacity'` ....etc"

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer..

```
 if (count($this->ar_like) > 0)
        {
            if (count($this->ar_where) == 0)
            {
                $this->ar_like[0] = str_replace(array('OR','AND'),'',$this->ar_like[0]);
            }

            $sql .= implode("\n", $this->ar_like);
        }
```

for more detail visit this thread 
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/99235/#501303